# Emacsのorg-babelでTypeScriptを書くとき、tsconfig.jsonはどこに置けば？

Tags: emacs, typescript

Emacsでorg-babelを使って、文書の中にTypeScriptのコード例を埋め込んでいます。
`.emacs.d/init.el`に追加したのは以下の行です。

```
(eval-after-load "org" '(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((typescript . t))))
(require 'typescript-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ts\\'" . typescript-mode))
(require 'tide)
```

この状態で、org-mode文書に以下のコードを埋め込み、エラーを発生させたいです。

```
#+BEGIN_SRC typescript :results output 
let data_1: string = undefined;
let data_2: string = null;
#+END_SRC
```

この場合`tsconfig.json`を以下のように指定すればいいんですよね。

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
}
```

ところで、この`tsconfig.json`はどこに置けばいいのでしょうか？

`~/.emacs.d/elpa/tide-20200327.1218/tsserver/tsconfig.json`というのがあったので、これを編集してオプションを追加し、念の為EmacsもLinuxもリスタートさせたのですが、有効化しませんでした。

コマンドラインの`tsc`でコンパイルしてみると、想定通り`strictNullChecks`が動作する（trueにするとエラーになり、falseにするとエラーにならない）ことを確認しました。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

英語版にも同趣旨の質問をしていましたが、回答のワークアラウンドで目的は達成できました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842382/how-to-apply-tsconfig-json-to-the-emacs-org-babel

```
#+BEGIN_SRC typescript :cmdline --strictNullChecks :results output 
let data_1: string = undefined;
let data_2: string = null;
#+END_SRC
```